# How to convert multiple documents from a single collection to a single document containing one array

Tags: mongodb

I have an aggregation pipeline that nearly does what I want. I've used match / unwind / project / sort to get 99% of the way. It is returning multiple documents:

```
[
{ 
    "_id" : 254.8
},
{ 
    "_id" : 93.7
},
{ 
    "_id" : 89.9
},
{ 
    "_id" : 94.15
},
{ 
    "_id" : 102.1
},
{ 
    "_id" : 93.9
},
{ 
    "_id" : 102.7
}
]
```

Note: I've added the array brackets and commas to make it more readable, but you can also read it as:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 254.8
}
{ 
    "_id" : 93.7
}
{ 
    "_id" : 89.9
}
{ 
    "_id" : 94.15
}
{ 
    "_id" : 102.1
}
```

I need the contents of the ID fields from all 7 documents in an array of values in one document:

```
{values: [254.8, 93.7, 89.9, 94.15, 102.1, 93.9, 102.7]}
```

It would be easy to sort this with JS once I have the results but I'd rather do it in the pipeline if possible so my JS stays 100% generic and only returns pure pipeline data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to complete the job:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "values": {
        $push: "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: false
    }
  }
])
```

The result will be:

```
[
  {
    "values": [
      254.8,
      93.7,
      89.9,
      94.15,
      102.1,
      93.9,
      102.7
    ]
  }
]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/pTmR_rni0J1

Comment: Thank you so much @codemonkey , that was driving me mad, knew it was going to be easy once you know how!